# Ansible print SSLcertificate expire days

Tags: ansible

I have this play to print certificate expire days. but its giving the AnsibleUndefined error. How to fix this error message.

Running this on Ansible 2.8 with Python 3.

**Tasks**

```
- name: Get a cert from an https port
  get_certificate:
    host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    port: 10250
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  run_once: true
  register: cert

- name: Cert output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ cert }}"

- name: How many days until cert expires
  debug:
    msg: "cert expires in: {{ expire_days }} days."
  vars:
    expire_days: "{{ (( cert.not_after | to_datetime('%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')) - (ansible_date_time.iso8601 | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')) ).days }}"
```

output and error message.

```
 "failed": false,
        "issuer": {
            "CN": "kubernetes"
        },
        "not_after": "20290827151600Z",
        "not_before": "20190830151600Z",
        "serial_number": 552511748902341611097595302509251707409941832746,
        "signature_algorithm": "sha256WithRSAEncryption",
     version": 2
    }
}



TASK [test : How many days until cert expires] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: []: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({{ (( cert.
not_after | to_datetime('%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')) - (ansible_date_time.iso8601 | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')) ).days }}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like
 '-': strptime() argument 1 must be str, not AnsibleUndefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/playbooks/roles/test/tasks/main.yaml': line 23, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depe
nding on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: How many days until cert expires\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running `gather_facts: no` setting. When I change it to `gather_facts: yes`. Now its working as expected.